# Hidden file field doesn't save into database

Tags: jquery, django, inline-formset

I'm trying to unhide initially hidden `media` filefield in form (type="hidden" > type="file") using jQuery so user can upload a file after clicking a button. The unhiding portion works flawlessly but despite file going in POST.FILES (I checked by `print(request.FILES)` at the beginning of the view) it's **not saved** into the database.

When I comment out `widgets={'media': HiddenInput,}` in `forms.py` and the filefield is visible from the beginning the file **is saved** to database without problems.

I guessing it could be some validation problem (django thinks it should be hidden field but gets file???).

How can I solve this problem so the file is saved to database from unhidden file field?

Comment: An input can only have one `type`. Please show the relevant code

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm changing the `type` attribute. Not adding another one. This is relevant jQuery code `$("#id_postblock_set-0-media").attr("type", "file");`

This:
`<input type="hidden" name="postblock_set-0-media" id="id_postblock_set-0-media">`
Becomes this:
`<input type="file" name="postblock_set-0-media" id="id_postblock_set-0-media">`

Comment: I think I found the problem. The `type` value is changed to `file` in HTML but in POST it's still sent as `type="hidden"`. I think it doesn't pass validation in `views.py` and so it doesn't save into database.